# Как узнать, какие потоки созданы конкретным модулем (lib) в памяти приложения?

Tags: delphi

Возможно, вопрос задан не вполне корректно, прошу за это прощения.
Нужно заморозить (`suspend`) все потоки приложения, кроме тех, которые созданы конкретным модулем и выполняются.

Функция для заморозки всех потоков в конкретном процессе выглядит так:

```
function SuspendProcess(PID:DWORD; mytid: dword):Boolean;
var
hSnap:  THandle;
THR32:  THREADENTRY32;
hOpen:  THandle;
begin
  Result := FALSE;
  hSnap := CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPTHREAD, 0);
  if hSnap <> INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE then
  begin
    THR32.dwSize := SizeOf(THR32);
    Thread32First(hSnap, THR32);
    repeat
      if THR32.th32OwnerProcessID = PID then
      begin
        hOpen := OpenThread($0002, FALSE, THR32.th32ThreadID);
        if hOpen <> INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE then
        begin
          Result := TRUE;
          SuspendThread(hOpen); // сюда я могу поставить проверку, но для этого нужно знать ид нужных потоков (которые не замораживать)
          CloseHandle(hOpen);
        end;
      end;
    until Thread32Next(hSnap, THR32) = FALSE;
    CloseHandle(hSnap);
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Посмотрите в сторону апишной **GetThreadInfo**